# How to pass the value of the Fetch API to a variable?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, fetch-api

Folks!

I'm trying to get the latitude or longitude of a location using the Google Maps API. But I don't know how to return a value using the Fetch API and its promises.

I can log the latitude and longitude with:

```
let url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=london'

fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data.results[0].geometry.location.lat)
    console.log(data.results[0].geometry.location.lng)
  })
```

**Output:**

```
51.5073509
0.1277583
```

But I want to encapsulate this code in a function:

```
function getLatitudeOrLongitude(url, LatitudeOrLongitude) {
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (LatitudeOrLongitude === 'latitude')
        return data.results[0].geometry.location.lat
      else
        return data.results[0].geometry.location.lng
    })
}

let latitudeOfLondon = getLatitudeOrLongitude(url, 'latitude')

console.log(latitudeOfLondon)
```

**Output:**

```
undefined
```

Could someone point me what is wrong? Thanks you all!

Edit: [Here](http://jsbin.com/muwoxig/edit?js,console) you can find a JS Bin with the code

Comment: You can't return from an asynchronous method.

Comment: Thanks @adeneo! What could I do instead to accomplish the same  task?

Comment: You can only use the result inside a callback, or in this case a `then` handler

Comment: I see. So I should try another library instead? Maybe jQuery's ajax?

Comment: Nope, all asynchronous code works the same way, you have to work with it, and access the data when it's actually returned.

Comment: Great to know, thank you so much @adeneo!

Answer (score 4):

You must use `.then` to handle the result of a promise:

```
function getLatitudeOrLongitude(url, LatitudeOrLongitude) {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (LatitudeOrLongitude === 'latitude')
        return data.results[0].geometry.location.lat
      else
        return data.results[0].geometry.location.lng
    })
}

getLatitudeOrLongitude(url, 'latitude')
  .then((latitudeOfLondon) => console.log(latitudeOfLondon));
```